# HintPath ignored when referencing an assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm referencing an assembly from a .NET project as follows:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Uc, Version=15.0.4603.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```

The project compiles fine; however, when trying to run the application, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Uc, Version=15.0.4603.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient(Boolean sideBySideLync)
   at lync_tester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\\Work\lync_tester\Program.cs:line 14
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Process Monitor shows that the application is trying to find the assembly everywhere *except* as specified by HintPath:

[image]

Also, for some reason most of the properties of that assembly, including "Copy Local", are greyed out:

[image]

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Mmmm...maybe if you mark this assembly to **copy local**?

Comment: `HintPath` is for compiler only. It does nor affect where runtime look for assemblies.

Comment: @JesusAngulo I can't; the property is disabled. For now I copied it manually to my project folder, but I don't like this solution very much.

Comment: @PetSerAl Okay, that's interesting. So how *do* I hint to the runtime where to look for it? Something in app.config? Or is shipping the dll with the application the only way to do it?

Comment: @PetSerAl Okay, I figured it out. You can write an answer if you wish, othewise I'll answer it myself if StackOverflow lets me.

Comment: What was the answer?